# Parse Issue With iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using a Parse account to post images, messages and username to a prototype cell. For some reason my username string is staying empty and thus not posting to the cell. Can you help? I'm fairly new to coding so this one has just stumped me.

```
​import UIKit
import Parse

class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var messages = [String]()
    var usernames = [String]()
    var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
    var users = [String: String]()
    var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

    @IBAction func logout(sender: AnyObject) {
        PFUser.logOut()

        var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

        performSegueWithIdentifier("logout", sender: self)
    }

    func swiped(gesture:UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
                performSegueWithIdentifier("feedSwipe", sender: self)

            //case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up:
                //print("User Swiped Up")

            //case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down:
                //print("User Swiped Down")

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
                performSegueWithIdentifier("feedSwipe", sender: self)

            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func refresh() {
        var query = PFUser.query()

        query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
            if let users = objects {
                self.messages.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.imageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

                for object in users {
                    if let user = object as? PFUser {
                        self.users[user.objectId!] = user.username!
                    }
                }
            }

        var getFollowedUsersQuery = PFQuery(className: "followers")

        getFollowedUsersQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

        getFollowedUsersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    var followedUser = object["following"] as! String
                    var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")

                    query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: followedUser)
                    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
                        if let objects = objects {    
                            for object in objects {
                                self.messages.append(object["message"]! as! String)
                                self.imageFiles.append(object["imageFile"]! as! PFFile)
                                self.usernames.append(self.users[object["userId"] as! String]!)

                                //self.usernames.append(followedUser)
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                                self.refresher.endRefreshing()

                                //print(followedUser)
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swiped:")

        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swiped:")

        swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swiped:")

        swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swiped:")

        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        refresher = UIRefreshControl()

        refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")

        refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)

        refresh()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

        return usernames.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell

        imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                myCell.postedImage.image  = downloadedImage
            }
        }

        myCell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]
        myCell.message.text = messages[indexPath.row]

        return myCell
    }
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you provided relates to the problem you are having...

Comment: I thought maybe, itd be something wrong with my query off of parse....I'm fairly new to coding so debugging this type of issue has been difficult for me.